# Read a specific sector of DVD by Pinvoke in C#

Tags: c#, file-io, pinvoke

I am reading directly from a disk using C# and pinvoking the kernel32 ReadFile method.i want just read a particular sector for save time but ReadFile read from first to N sector. How can read only own sector with my choice?

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct OVERLAPPED
    {
        public uint Internal;
        public uint InternalHigh;
        public uint Offset;
        public uint OffsetHigh;
        public int hEvent;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int CreateFile(string filename, uint desiredAccess, uint shareMode, IntPtr attributes, uint creationDisposition, uint flagsAndAttributes, IntPtr templateFile);

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Boolean CloseHandle(int handle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Boolean ReadFile(IntPtr hFile, Byte[] buffer, UInt32 BytesToRead, ref UInt32 BytedRead, OVERLAPPED OverLapped);
    static int EIGHT_K = 8192;
    static int FIVE_TWELVE_BYTES = 512;
    static uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
    static uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
    static uint FILE_SHARE_READ = 1;
    static uint FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 2;

    [STAThread]
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int fileHandle = 0;
        bool returnVal = true;

        try
        {
            // Open the device specified (Using the boot partition)
            string deviceName = @"\\.\f:";
            fileHandle = CreateFile(deviceName, GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, (IntPtr)0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0,(IntPtr)0);
            if (fileHandle != -1)
            {
                Byte[] sector = new Byte[EIGHT_K];
                UInt32 bytesRead = (uint)EIGHT_K;
                OVERLAPPED ol = new OVERLAPPED();

                // Can't get a FileStream ctor to work so I am using Win32 API ReadFile
                bool worked = ReadFile((IntPtr)fileHandle, sector, (uint)EIGHT_K, ref bytesRead, ol);
                return;

            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseHandle(fileHandle);
        }
        return;
    }
```

I want to mark the DVD till required Original DVD to run the program.

Comment: So, what happens? I can see a few errors in the code. But it's as if you've not even run it. If you'd run it you'd tell us how it failed.

Comment: only this line must change "static int EIGHT_K = 8192;". now fixed and work in my PC but this code read from First byte to 8192 (or anything)  but I only need own sector choice myself.

Comment: Yes . exactly but how ?

Comment: @user3799713 Hello! Can you upload the final version of the code? I need this for marking the original DVD too. Or can you explain me how are you reading the file without creating this file? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Plz Email to me xwpedram@yahoo.com .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `OVERLAPPED` struct is declared poorly and is incorrect in a 64 bit process. But in any case you don't need it. You are not performing overlapped I/O. Which is just as well because the declaration of `ReadFile` is incorrect. That function wants a pointer to an `OVERLAPPED` struct. You pass it by value.

In any case, you just don't need to consider overlapped I/O. So fix this issue by deleting the `OVERLAPPED` struct declaration from your code. And declare `ReadFile` like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern Boolean ReadFile(IntPtr hFile, Byte[] buffer, 
    UInt32 BytesToRead, out UInt32 BytedRead, IntPtr Overlapped);
```

Pass `IntPtr.Zero` as the `Overlapped` parameter. And do make sure that you check the return value of `ReadFile` for an error.

The next step is to seek to a location in the file. Use `SetFilePointerEx` for that.

```
DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool SetFilePointerEx(IntPtr hFile, long liDistanceToMove,
   out long lpNewFilePointer, uint dwMoveMethod);
```

Consult the documentation for [`SetFilePointerEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365542.aspx) to work out how to call this function.

Since you are using direct disk access, you will of course need to align the reads to sector boundaries.